# Can paypal Parallel Payments be used in rest api?

Tags: api, rest, paypal

Is there any way currently to do a parallel payment in paypal with the rest api? I am building a mobile application and can only use the rest api system however there is no documentation on how you can use parallel payments with REST.

You can do everything else so it seems to me like the developers got to that feature and just gave up :P.

This feature is a huge part of our website and if we cannot use it on the mobile app it will mean we have to redo how we handle transactions on the site so that both areas are consistent.

If this feature is not available since rest was supposed to be the refresh of all their API's to support newer tech is it coming? Does anyone know and if you do any information on a timeline would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

REST API does not support parallel payments at this time, it's in the product road map but not yet in the released APIs.

An alternative for your use case is to integrate the webview embedded Express Checkout flow into your APP, it provides the most identical experience to payers since the new UI was released.